# Married to overpair?

Tags: betting-strategy, cash-game, all-in, heads-up

I just played a cash game hand yesterday that made me wonder if I'm too married to my overpairs. It's a headsup game, and we both have about 40X, with me slightly ahead.
I wake up to QQ and raise to 4X preflop (my standard raise for the past hour). Villain calls. Flop is 442, I bet 5X, villain calls. Turn is 9, I bet 10X, villain calls. River is another 4, I shove. He calls and shows J9. Is it dangerous to shove on a board with potential quads like that, especially if he's calling two streets before that??

Comment: Could you clarify, is it just this hand your playing heads up or is there only two of you at the table?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you only worried about quads?

What beats you?
4
99
KK
AA

What hand might call that you beat?
JJ - 33  (except 99)
2x
9x

Hero should not have called pre flop with 2x

Pre flop call with 4x is wrong.  And he does not have 44 with 3 on the board.

Pre flop villain should have raised AA, KK
In heads up you would likely get a raise from 99

Call pre flop with
A9 suited or 99 is in the range
J9 to me is a marginal call but this is heads up so OK

To me that is a good shove
VERY unlikely you are beat - to me just 99
The only hands (9x) that would call would likely call a big bet

In head up I don't really blame villain for making that call
He is only losing to AA-99 as 4 is not likely in your range

On the turn you were both pretty much pot committed

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for the sake of argument that J9 is the worst hand this player calls the `river` with.

Your hand beats and gets paid by: J9+,TT,JJ (54 combinations of hands)

You hand loses to: KK,AA,99,42+ (59 combinations of hands)

Using ***this alone*** we see that it is barely not a profitable shove:

54/113 * 20BB - 59/113 * 20BB = -0.88BB EV

However, let's now consider a much more realistic `Big Blind` defending range and `river` calling range:

- **Remove TT-AA** - These would probably 3-Bet pre-flop. I would include 99 too, except considering you are worried that 4's full of Q's 40BB deep with a SPR of 1:1 may not be a shove I'm going to assume the game dynamic to be passive.
- **Remove 42-Q4** - Your opponent is unlikely to defend the `Big Blind` with these hands.
- **Add 97+,T9** to the opponents `river` calling range - Likely he would defend the BB with these hands and is certainly not folding the `river` if we know s/he calls with J9.

In a standard HU you could add more hands such as medium pairs that bluff catch, heck even Ace High; but as I said above I'm assuming the game dynamic is not aggressive at all.

Now the EV becomes profitable:

78/89 * 20BB - 11/89 * 20BB = +15BB

This is a monster profit in the long term given the stack sizes.

Comment: To make it even better, by the river the hand combinations including a 4 are dramatically reduced by the simple fact that 3 of them are already on the board.  Likewise, there are fewer 99 combinations now since we know there's one that villain cannot have

Comment: I believe I already took that into consideration.

Comment: I didn't try to verify all of it, but it just stuck out to me that there were 59 combinations for AA,KK,99,42+.  How did you get to that number?

Comment: 6xAA, 6xKK, 3x99, (3x42, 4x43, 4x54, 4x64, 4x74, 4x84, 3x94, 4xT4, 4xJ4, 2xQ4, 4xK4, 4xA4) = 59 total combinations

Comment: You're totally right, I don't know what I was thinking before.